# How to get a list of SQL query paramerters for PHP OCI?

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle, oracle-call-interface

My application is executing user-defined SQL statements that contain query parameters. To detect the parameter names that should be passed to `oci_bind_by_name` I use a simple reg-ex pattern like `/:\w+/` but this fails for string literals and comments contained in the SQL statement.

```
BEGIN
   /* some unused :param here */
   SELECT 'some other :param there' FROM foo;
END;
```

Handling string literal detection and comment by more reg-ex patterns seems like a bad idea when thinking about even more nasty examples like:

```
BEGIN
   SELECT '/* some comment :literals --' FROM foo;
   -- some more comment :literals */
END;
```

Is there some way to get the required query parameter names for binding using OCI8 functions? What other possibilities do exist without falling back to manually parsing SQL in user code?

Comment: Those PL/SQL blocks do not technically contain bind variables.  A better example would be `begin select :bind_variable from foo; end;`.  Are you really looking for bind variables or are you creating your own custom templating solution?

Comment: Indeed your PL/SQL code would be a positive example for finding bind parameters using a re-ex like `/:\w+/`. But how to exclude the negative examples from the post? Not sure if I understand the meaning of "templating solution" correctly, but it seems to fit for this situation where the application's event handlers are stored as as user-defined PL/SQL code and the code has to find out what bind parameters to supply for execution.

Answer (score 1):

My code below is not a great way to solve this problem.  Before you use that code, keep looking for a more official solution.

It appears that OCI does have functionality to dynamically retrieve bind names, through the function [OCIStmtGetBindInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14250/oci15rel003.htm#sthref2656).  However, it also looks like that function is not available in the [default PHP functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.oci8.php).  Maybe there are other, more advanced ways of connecting PHP to Oracle that supply the necessary function, but I don't know enough about OCI or PHP to find them.

---

If you're ready for a not-so-great solution, you can use my open source program [plsql_lexer](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer/) to find the bind variable names.  The lexer breaks SQL statements into small tokens, and handles difficult syntax issues like comments and strings.  The results should be much more accurate than using a few regular expressions.

The downside is that the program is not a full parser, and you have to deal with the primitive tokens.  In this case, it's relatively easy to find 99.9999% of the bind variables with a single SQL statement.  After installing the program, put your SQL into the middle of the following SELECT statement:

```sql
--Find bind variables.
--(Words or numerics that were immediately preceded (excluding whitespace) by a colon.)
select to_char(value) bind_variable_name
from
(
    --Get previous token.
    select type, value, first_char_position,
        lag(to_char(type)) over (order by first_char_position) previous_type
    from
    (
        --Convert to tokens, ignore whitespace.
        select type, value, first_char_position
        from table(plsql_lexer.lex(
            q'[
                --Here's the actual SQL statement you care about.
                --/*:fake_bind1*/
                select 1 a
                from dual
                where 1 = : real_bind_1 and :real_bind_2 = ':fake_bind_2'
            ]'))
        where type not in ('whitespace')
        order by first_char_position
    )
)
where type in ('numeric', 'word')
    and previous_type = ':'
order by first_char_position;


BIND_VARIABLE_NAME
------------------
real_bind_1
real_bind_2
```

There may still be some weird cases this code doesn't handle.  For example, a bind variable can be a quoted identifier, you may need to handle the double quotes.  And the above code doesn't handle [indicators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Placeholder-Expressions.html#GUID-B98B5394-A573-4BF8-9EC3-7B1BB1130553).  On the other hand, I have literally never seen either of those features used, so it may not matter to you.  Test thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I wrote some small state machine for parsing SQL statement bind parameters and put it into a helper class to not conflict with other globals:

```php
class SqlBindNames {
   private static function isLineBreak($ch) {
      return (($ch === "\r") || ($ch === "\n"));
   }

   private static function isIdentChar($ch) {
      return (($ch >= 'a') && ($ch <= 'z')) ||
             (($ch >= 'A') && ($ch <= 'Z')) ||
             (($ch >= '0') && ($ch <= '9')) ||
             ($ch === '_');
   }

   private const QUOTE_SINGLE_CHR    = '\'';
   private const QUOTE_DOUBLE_CHR    = '"';
   private const COMMENT_LINE_STR    = "--";
   private const COMMENT_BEGIN_STR   = "/*";
   private const COMMENT_END_STR     = "*/";
   private const BIND_START_CHR      = ':';

   private const MODE_NORMAL         = 0;
   private const MODE_QUOTE_SINGLE   = 1;
   private const MODE_QUOTE_DOUBLE   = 2;
   private const MODE_COMMENT_LINE   = 3;
   private const MODE_COMMENT_MULTI  = 4;
   private const MODE_BIND_VARNAME   = 5;

   public static function getSqlBindNames(string $sql, bool $unique = true) {
      $mode = self::MODE_NORMAL;
      $names = array();
      $namesIndex = array();
      $len = strlen($sql);
      $i = 0;

      while ($i < $len) {
         $curr = $sql[$i];
         if ($i < $len - 1) {
            $next = $sql[$i + 1];
         } else {
            $next = "\0";
         }
         $nextMode = $mode;

         if ($mode === self::MODE_NORMAL) {
            if ($curr === self::QUOTE_SINGLE_CHR) {
               $nextMode = self::MODE_QUOTE_SINGLE;
            } else if ($curr === self::QUOTE_DOUBLE_CHR) {
               $nextMode = self::MODE_QUOTE_DOUBLE;
            } else if (($curr === self::COMMENT_LINE_STR[0]) && ($next === self::COMMENT_LINE_STR[1])) {
               $i += 1;
               $nextMode = self::MODE_COMMENT_LINE;
            } else if (($curr === self::COMMENT_BEGIN_STR[0]) && ($next === self::COMMENT_BEGIN_STR[1])) {
               $i += 1;
               $nextMode = self::MODE_COMMENT_MULTI;
            } else if (($curr === self::BIND_START_CHR) && self::isIdentChar($next)) {
               $bindName = "";
               $nextMode = self::MODE_BIND_VARNAME;
            }
         } else if (($mode === self::MODE_QUOTE_SINGLE) && ($curr === self::QUOTE_SINGLE_CHR)) {
            $nextMode = self::MODE_NORMAL;
         } else if (($mode === self::MODE_QUOTE_DOUBLE) && ($curr === self::QUOTE_DOUBLE_CHR)) {
            $nextMode = self::MODE_NORMAL;
         } else if (($mode === self::MODE_COMMENT_LINE) && self::isLineBreak($curr)) {
            $nextMode = self::MODE_NORMAL;
         } else if (($mode === self::MODE_COMMENT_MULTI) && ($curr === self::COMMENT_END_STR[0]) && ($next === self::COMMENT_END_STR[1])) {
            $i += 1;
            $nextMode = self::MODE_NORMAL;
         } else if ($mode === self::MODE_BIND_VARNAME) {
            if (self::isIdentChar($curr)) {
               $bindName = $bindName . $curr;
            }
            if (!self::isIdentChar($next)) {
               /* found new bind param */
               if (!$unique || !in_array(strtolower($bindName), $namesIndex)) {
                  array_push($namesIndex, strtolower($bindName));
                  array_push($names, $bindName);
               }
               $nextMode = self::MODE_NORMAL;
            }
         }

         $i += 1;
         $mode = $nextMode;
      }

      return $names;
   }
}
```

It seems to work, improvements are welcome!